# What is difference between "PowerSlide" and "Drift"?

Tags: terminology

I noticed some games use the term *Powerslides* and others use *Drifting*, but is there a difference?

I mean generally, not specifically to single game. Some games call the action Powerslide and some call it drift. For example, Crash Team Racing calls it Powerslide but Burnout 3 Takedown calls it drift.

What is the difference? Is there a difference?

Comment: Meta discussion: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12927/whats-up-with-the-excessive-close-and-downvotes-lately

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This video shows the difference between those two in GTA:

...or Forza:

In short, a drift starts before the apex of a corner while a powerslide starts behind it.

- Drift = oversteer on your way *in*
- Powerslide = oversteer on your way *out*

And for those who want more insight: A real life explanation of Drifting vs. Powerslides:

Comment: Does this difference actually manifest in those games though?  I'm interested to know if "powerslide" or "drift" are misnomers in some scenarios; and thus used interchangeably, or if the games actually do differentiate in how these are pulled off.  Or do most games allow both but only stick to one name?

Comment: @JMac that depends on the game(s) you're talking about. If you want to know that for a specific game you should ask a new question specifically about that one. There is now way to talk about numbers or percentages of games using the terms correctly. There are way too many games out there. This question here is only about the general terminology.

Comment: I think that makes this pretty off-topic then, no?  There's the claim that the terminology is the same as in gaming; but you're only reference is for actual vehicles.  I'd think the answer should at least address the difference between powerslides and drifts _in games_; or else this is just a racing terminology question/answer.

Comment: @JMac not necessarily. It is just not possible to check all the games whether or not they use those terms. Do you know how many racing games are out there? The community still does use them (as Robotnik already suggested in the comments of the question). When I ask my friends (primarily Gran Turismo) they do know what we're talking about. Anyway, the question is not about where it's being used, it's about what it means.

Comment: I accepting this as answer. It is well explained and well understandable There is not much difference between game terminologi and real terminologi because racing games are usually simulation of reality.

Comment: @dly If the answer is only about what it means _in real life_, then it's not much of a gaming question/answer... is it?

Comment: @JMac Just as Garrom and Robotnik already said... the gaming community adopted the terminology. After all racing games are racing too. Only because there is a chance some games use the term incorrectly doesn't mean this question is off-topic.

Comment: @JMac As i said, There is not much difference between game terminologi and real terminologi because racing games are usually simulation of reality. It is about games by same amount as about reality because racing games are usually simulation of reality.

Comment: @Garrom If you just wanted to know the definition of driving terms why did you ask it on gaming stack exchange?

Comment: @JMac Well, CTR, FlatOut, BurnOut, Juiced, NFS are GAMES what are all about DRIVING. I named just few but there are a LOT of them.

Comment: @Garrom Yes; but your question wasn't really about what "powersliding" and "drifting" meant _in those games_.  You really seemed to care what those terms mean in real life.  For example, in CTR, are you able to oversteer before _and_ after the apex of turns?  If so, does the game always call this "powersliding" even if it's technically drifting?  The games are about driving; but if your question isn't specific to how any game is using the terms, I really don't see why you would want an answer here when you're looking for the real life answer.

Comment: @JMac since my answer is referencing GTA now, may it stay on this site please? :)

Comment: @JMac I was not asking about specific game because i was asking about gameplay mechanism in general, mechanism shared among all racing games. I accepted this answer because it fits to most of top-level games (games about profesional, realistic driving). Because mechanism is shared among all racing games what i should do by your option ? Tag every racing game ever created ?

Answer (score 6):

While dly's answer covers the more technical definition of the terms, I thought I'd address some points specifically about CTR, as the concept is slightly different in that game.

In Crash Team Racing, 'Powersliding' refers to the entire 'slide' action, from the moment you land your kart and begin the slide, until the moment you release the bunny-hop/drift button (or spin-out). Note that in this definition the slide is not about 'oversteering' or putting your foot down to get the back wheels to spin - you aren't entering a slide because of a loss of traction, you're physically bunny-hopping the kart into a sideways alignment (relative to the direction of travel):

[image: Crash Bandicoot bunny hopping into a powerslide]
<sub>Animated Gif from the [NeoGAF forums](https://www.neogaf.com/threads/crash-bandicoot-retrospective-crash-team-racing.1223970/)</sub>

This is described in the in-game Adventure Mode hints as such:

> #### Power Sliding Hint
>
> You can go faster through turns by power sliding. To access the power slide, press and hold the R1 button while turning hard.
> <sub>- [Aku Aku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RCkxLDPS88) and [Uka Uka](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7noERkcCfwQ) Hints</sub>

And on Wikipedia:

> A crucial maneuver in Crash Team Racing is the power slide; the player executes the slide by holding down one of the shoulder buttons to perform a hop, and steering before the kart lands.
> <sub>[Crash Team Racing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_Team_Racing)</sub>

However, note that despite this in-game use, the terms 'powerslide' and 'drift' are used [pretty much interchangeably](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/196989-crash-team-racing/56027416) by the community, sometimes even combining to two. NeoGAF User RK128 describes the powerslide mechanic as such:

> The power drifting is also very different from Mario Kart, where instead of drifting until you get a colored spark to tell you 'Let go to move fast' you rather use one trigger to drift and the opposite trigger when the drift bar is green. You can do this up to three times and it makes drifting so rewarding in CTR.
> <sub>[Crash Bandicoot Retrospective - Crash Team Racing](https://www.neogaf.com/threads/crash-bandicoot-retrospective-crash-team-racing.1223970/) - NeoGAF Forums</sub>

And this PlayStation LifeStyle article uses both terms but leans toward 'drifting' over 'powerslide':

> Powerslides and drifting also took a notable upgrade in CTR. Drifting around turns has almost always been a simple way to get a small boost since Mario Kart 64 in 1996. However, Crash Team Racing was the first to explore the concept of the powered-up boost. Drifting around corners built up a boost meter and toggling a boost just before a catastrophic spin-out would allow players to score a better version of the regular boost, making drifting a special exercise timing and precision.
> <sub>["It's Time for Crash Team Racing: Remastered](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2017/08/22/its-time-for-crash-team-racing-remastered/) - T.J. Denzer, August 22, 2017</sub>

Note that the 'boost' mechanic is a separate action to a Powerslide. It's known as Turbo Boost in game, or sometimes 'Drift Boost', 'Slide Boost' or simply 'boosting' by the community. It's worth mentioning but it's a large enough topic all to itself so let's just focus on the slide part of the mechanic here.

So to directly answer your question:

> Is there a difference?

I can't speak for Burnout as I've never played it, and I'm sure more simulation-racing games like Gran Turismo probably differentiate between the terms in the manner described by dly's answer, but for CTR specifically? There isn't really a difference. You should be ok to use them interchangeably in this context.